# Windstride cost calculation

Tags: blade-and-soul

Windstriding costs money and scales up with respect to the distance covered. What is the calculation behind determining the amount it takes to windstride? Does it depend on current character / equipment level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on distance and only on distance.

But since BnS world is not seamless and locations are connected only 'virtually', the distances between Windstriding points not always seem fair. Windstriding cost for each location's pairs are just hardcoded in a game since development.

You can lower the price by buying Premium.